# Jenkins slave pod keeps always running

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to keep always the slave pod running. Unfortunately using Kubernetes agent inside the pipeline, I am still struggling with adding "podRetention" as always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a declarative pipeline you would use idleMinutes to keep the pod longer

```
pipeline {
    agent {
       kubernetes {
            label "myPod"
            defaultContainer 'docker'
            yaml readTrusted('kubeSpec.yaml')
            idleMinutes 30
        }
    }
```

the idea is to keep the pod alive for a certain time for jobs that are triggered often, the one watching master branch for instance. That way if developers are on rampage pushing on master, the build will be fast. When devs are done we don't need the pod to be up forever and we don't want to pay extra resources for nothing so we let the pod kill itself

Comment: After adding ```idleMinutes 30``` in podTemplate, it creates new slave(pod) on each build-

```NAME                                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
jenkins-6d44798b69-tr8tb                                  1/1     Running   0          44h

worker-bf23af92-2159-4a09-84ae-b277db073aab-756bc-9sgcw   2/2     Running   0          33s

worker-be4c3286-e3a3-46f1-9cde-56761ad1a33b-2d0f6-2d65x   2/2     Running   0          3m


worker-dc99e7e8-b890-4315-99b4-72391799f60a-nc4l4-18ldv   2/2     Running   0          4m```

Comment: One thing also noticed, worker node(slave/pod) are still running more than 30 min which is aginst podTemplate spec- 
```NAME                                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
jenkins-6d44798b69-tr8tb                                  1/1     Running   0          45h
worker-bf23af92-2159-4a09-84ae-b277db073aab-756bc-9sgcw   1/2     Running   0          31m
worker-be4c3286-e3a3-46f1-9cde-56761ad1a33b-2d0f6-2d65x   1/2     Running   0          33m
worker-dc99e7e8-b890-4315-99b4-72391799f60a-nc4l4-18ldv   1/2     Running   0          34m

Comment: it worked. thanks. 

By applying this approach, we may fell in situation if we add another container inside podTemplate and those steps(pipeline stage) which are scheduled to execute on that container, it will definetely fail. 

It would be greatful if Jenkins master force to recreate slave(pod) if any modification is done inside podTemplate.

Comment: indeed a situation like that could occur. What you could do if you are using github for instance is lock the pod specification file to require your validation before being merged. That way you will be noticed if someone else update the file and you'll know you need to recreate the pod. You could also put the date of the day as a variable in the label, that way jenkins will create a new pod every day

Comment: I got the case and to overcome this, we configure Jenkins job as "Pipeline script" instaed of "Pipepilne script from SCM".      Is there any way to send "alert" to Jenkins master to recreate the idle slave(pod) with updated podTempalte if configuration is changed itself in Jenkins (UI).

Comment: I would create a Job with at least two stages
1). first it will try to remove all the pods with something like
`for (aSlave in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.slaves) {
    if (aSlave.getComputer()..getLabelString()  ==~ /custompod-.*/) {
        aSlave.getComputer().setTemporarilyOffline(true,null);
        aSlave.getComputer().doDoDelete();
    }
}`
2). I would regenerate the jobs using jobdsl. I made a library to facilitate this step, have a look at this sample and the readme at the root of the project as well https://github.com/SAP/jenkins-pipelayer/blob/master/sample/jobs/Jenkinsfile

Comment: I worked on the idleMinutes feature myself and would appreciate knowing why I got a downvote in 2021? have you noticed a regression?